# Why mentioning monic is important for gcd and lcm?

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, gcd-and-lcm

Let  $F$  is  a  field and  $F[x]$  be  the  polynomial  ring  over  $F$. Now  in the  definition  of  the  gcd  or  lcm  of  any  two  polynomials  $g(x)$  and  $f(x)$  it  is  mentioned  that the gcd  or  lcm  are  monic  polynomials .  My  question  is  why  this  "$monic$"  is  important. If  we  have  two  polynomials  with  real  coefficients,  say $\ \ $$5x^{2}$$\ \ $  and  $\ $$\ $ $25x$$\ \ $   then  the  lcm would  be$\ \ $ $25x^{2}$$\ \ $  and  the  gcd is  $\ \ $$5x$$\ \ $  none  of  which  is  monic. Then? Or did  I  got  the gcd, lcm  wrong?

Comment: We are working over a field so $5x$ divides $x$. The author is saying monic to pick out a unique gcd. An alternative is to call all $kx$ where $k\ne 0$ gcds.

Answer (score 2):

If $F$ is a field, then, in $F[x]$, if $f$ divides $g$, then so does $\alpha f$ for any non-zero $\alpha \in F$. Requiring the gcd to be monic makes it unique. In your example with $F = \mathbb{R}$, $6x$ or $72x$ would be just as good values for $\gcd(5x^2, 25x)$ if we didn't adopt this convention (not all authors do). If the ring of coefficients is not a field, then you can't adopt this convention (and in the absence of some other convention the gcd is not unique: it is only determined up to multiplication by a unit): in $\mathbb{Z}[x]$ your answer of $5x$ as **a** greatest common divisor of $5x^2$ and $25x$ is correct and there is one other correct answer, namely $-5x$. Similar remarks apply to the lcm.